# The parameterized query which was not supplied in windowsapplication

Tags: c#, datagridview, ado.net

In my Desktop application i import to excel sheet to datagridview and insert that rows into database in that i am getting exception when i open to see my database table it inserted all records.
my exception is:

> Additional information: The parameterized query
>   '(@CurrentCodeAssignment nvarchar(4000), @EffectiveOctober1 nvarch'
>   expects the parameter '@CurrentCodeAssignment', which was not
>   supplied.

my tried code:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("databseconnection");
  string str = "insert into xcelToDB(CurrentCodeAssignment,EffectiveOctober1,PreviousCodeAssignment)Values(@CurrentCodeAssignment,@EffectiveOctober1,@PreviousCodeAssignment)";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCodeAssignment", row.Cells["Current code assignment"].Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EffectiveOctober1", row.Cells["Effective October 1"].Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PreviousCodeAssignment", row.Cells["Previous Code(s) Assignment"].Value);
  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
MessageBox.Show("Records inserted");
```

can anyone tell me how to do this
Thank you

Comment: Whati s this?  ` @EffectiveOctober1 nvarch'  `, shouldn't it be nvarchar or something?

Comment: @EffectiveOctober1 my parameter name it taken as in database varchar(max)